# How to write a function that will create an object from several objects with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Good afternoon, I had a difficulty. I faced a problem that I can’t solve. I have an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        date: "2020-04-20",
        groups: ["apple"],
        type: ["fruit"],
    },
    {
        date: "2020-04-20",
        groups: ["potate"],
        type: ["vegetable"],
    },
    {
        date: "2020-04-23",
        groups: ["burger"],
        type: ["fastfood"],
    },
    {
        date: "2020-04-24",
        groups: ["cola"],
        type: ["water"],
    }
]
```

I need to write a function that will determine to cross two objects into one by date.
That is, the expected result that the function will return should be like this:

```
[
    {
        date: "2020-04-20",
        groups: ["apple", "potate"],
        type: ["fruit", "vegetable"],
    },
    {
        date: "2020-04-23",
        groups: ["burger"],
        type: ["fastfood"],
    },
    {
        date: "2020-04-24",
        groups: ["cola"],
        type: ["water"],
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can help you fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider what you are trying to accomplish. You want to merge data together. A good tool for this, as well as changing from one data structure to another is `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Conceptually, I'd suggest creating a map between the date and the entire object. This will help you determine if the entry already exists. Then, you can push the relevant keys to the relevant arrays as you iterate. Finally, you can use `Object.values` to get only the values of the map you created.

This is a pattern I use frequently for these sorts of situarions.

I would do something like the following:

```js
const input = [
    {
        date: "2020-04-20",
        groups: ["apple"],
        type: ["fruit"],
    },
    {
        date: "2020-04-20",
        groups: ["potate"],
        type: ["vegetable"],
    },
    {
        date: "2020-04-23",
        groups: ["burger"],
        type: ["fastfood"],
    },
    {
        date: "2020-04-24",
        groups: ["cola"],
        type: ["water"],
    }
];

const combine = (arr) => {
  const dateMap = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (!acc[item.date]) {
      acc[item.date] = item;
    } else {
      acc[item.date].groups = [...acc[item.date].groups, ...item.groups];
      acc[item.date].type = [...acc[item.date].type, ...item.type];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(dateMap);
};

console.log(combine(input));
```

Comment: only code doesn't help. If you can write some explanation then it will be more understandable what your code is doing

Comment: With a library, things are easier, take a look here: http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html

Comment: That's definitely a fair critique. I do want to help folks become better programmers. I just added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a standard grouping with an object for collecting the values.

```js
var data = [{ date: "2020-04-20", groups: ["apple"], type: ["fruit"] }, { date: "2020-04-20", groups: ["potate"], type: ["vegetable"] }, { date: "2020-04-23", groups: ["burger"], type: ["fastfood"] }, { date: "2020-04-24", groups: ["cola"], type: ["water"] }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.date] = r[o.date] || { date: o.date, groups: [], type: [] };
        r[o.date].groups.push(...o.groups);
        r[o.date].type.push(...o.type);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with `forEach`. Give this a try:

```js
var sortedData=[];
var data = [{ date: "2020-04-20", groups: ["apple"], type: ["fruit"] }, { date: "2020-04-20", groups: ["potate"], type: ["vegetable"] }, { date: "2020-04-23", groups: ["burger"], type: ["fastfood"] }, { date: "2020-04-24", groups: ["cola"], type: ["water"] }];
data.forEach((elem, index, arr)=>{
      isDatePresent= sortedData.some((value)=>value.date==elem.date);
      if(!isDatePresent){
        sortedData.push(elem);
      } else {
        var index=sortedData.findIndex((value)=> value.date==elem.date);
        sortedData[index].groups= [...sortedData[index].groups, ...elem.groups];
        sortedData[index].type= [...sortedData[index].type, ...elem.groups];
      }
});

console.log(sortedData)
```